# How to transform this list of lists into an array?

Tags: r, arrays, list, reshape

How can I transform the following list of lists

```
n = 10
m = 10
p = 5

l = list()
for(i in 1:m) {
  l[[i]] = list(
    X = matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n),
    Y = matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
  )
}
```

into an array with `dim = c(n, m * p, 2)`? Where the third index refers to the separation between X and Y, while the columns of the dataframe and the list components gets merged into the columns of the final array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```r
ar <- sapply(Reduce(\(a, b) lapply(seq_along(a), \(i) cbind(a[[i]], b[[i]])), l), 
             identity, simplify='array')
dim(ar)
# [1] 10 50  2
```

It succesively `cbind`s the X and Y matrices together and then uses `sapply` with `identity` function to turn the resulting list into an array.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you have to use a list at all?
You could also just pre-allocate an array and fill it in:

```r
m <- n <- 10
p <- 5
ret_array <- array(dim = c(n, m * p, 2))

for(i in 1:m) {
  ret_array[, seq_len(p) + p * (i - 1), 1] <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
  ret_array[, seq_len(p) + p * (i - 1), 2] <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), nrow = n)
}
```